# Iterating two list with different objects and comparing one parameter

Tags: android, kotlin

I have two list declared as :

```
private var answersList: MutableSet<AnswerRequest> = mutableSetOf()
private var answerListCreated: MutableSet<AnswerResponse> = mutableSetOf()
```

AnswerRequest only contains a `String` inside, and `AnswerResponse` contains more attributes, like `Int`, `String`, `Boolean`, so what I'm trying to achieve is to iterate on `answerListCreated` and find inside the same `String` as `answerList` for instance.

answerList contains : "Hello","Bye","Cucu"

answerListCreated contains ; {"Hello",3,false},{...}

So I'm trying to find the "Hello" word in `answerListCreated` so I can get the `id`.

What I'm doing from now is :

```
answerListCreated.forEach { a1->
            correctAnswersList.forEach { a2->
                if(a1.answerToQuestion == a2.answerToQuestion){
                    //Get the a1.id
                }
            }
        }
```

But I don't know why, is going to the if statement twice, it it's a `Set` this list doesn't have repeated ones, right? Is there any other way to do that?

### EDIT

List1 Just strings 
List2 Objects result from API, they have the same String of List1, but then I can check the Id.

```
data class ListExample1 (val text : String)
data class ListExample2 (val text : String, val id: Int, val exist: Boolean)
```

Comment: Please add full working code which we can run.

Comment: you are trying to do something like this right?
`answerListCreated.first { answersList.any { answerRequest -> answerRequest.answerToQuestion == it.answerToQuestion } }.id`

Comment: did you `break` the loop properly?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is, I have a list of full Strings, and another list which contains those objects from db, there are the same than first one, but on the other one I have the Id so I can deal with that object, it means List1 : Strings List2: ObjectResponse, I have to find the List1 String inside the ObjectResponse so I can get the List2.id

Comment: add AnswerRequest and AnswerResponse model class.

Comment: @SandeepInsan Added